# How to concatenate strings in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want my two strings to be diplayed on just a single line. Is it possible for it to appear like this:

***Curry Stephen***

using this code

**Text="{Binding EMP_LAST_NAME + EMP_FIRST_NAME}"** ? ? ?

I currently have this code. Thanks a lot.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeesList}"
        HasUnevenRows="True">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <controls:CircleImage Source="icon.png"
               HeightRequest="66"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               Aspect="AspectFill"
               WidthRequest="66"
               Grid.RowSpan="2"
               />

        <Label Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Text="{Binding EMP_LAST_NAME}"
               TextColor="White"
               FontSize="18"
               Opacity="0.6"/>

        <Label Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Text="{Binding EMP_FIRST_NAME}"
               TextColor="White"
               FontSize="18"
               Opacity="0.6"/>



      </Grid>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't bind to multiple properties on a `View` `Element`.

In this case you should create a new property which does the format you want and bind it to the `View`.

Example:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }    
    public string LastName { get; set; }    
    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

Then in `XAML`:

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
```

---

**Another approach:**

**As suggested in the comments** we can also use `FormattedText` property in a `Label`:

```
<Label.FormattedText>
   <FormattedString>
     <Span Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
     <Span Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
   </FormattedString>
</Label.FormattedText>
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `FormattedText` property in xamarin forms `Label` as follow:

```
<Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span TextColor="White" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding EMP_LAST_NAME'}"/>
            <Span TextColor="White" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding EMP_FIRST_NAME}"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

[Xamarin.Forms Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label)

And also you can add `Style` to avoid code duplication for `TextColor`, `FontSize` and other properties in your code.

[Styling Xamarin.Forms Apps using XAML Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/index)

Answer (score 6):

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='string before value {0:F0} string after value'}"/>
```

Suppose your value is 1234.
The output will be in this case:

> string before value 1234 string after value

Answer (score 4):

You could use `IValueConverter`, which will accept `Employee` and will return full name.

Or you could use [MultiComponentLabel](https://github.com/gromadskyi/SuperForms/blob/master/SuperForms/Shared/SuperForms.Controls/MultiComponentLabel.cs). It allows you to bind couple different values to one `Label`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage x:Name="Page"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SuperForms.Controls;assembly=SuperForms.Controls"
             x:Class="SuperForms.Samples.MultiComponentLabelPage">
  <controls:MultiComponentLabel Margin="0,20,0,0">
    <controls:MultiComponentLabel.Components>
      <controls:TextComponent Text="{Binding EMP_LAST_NAME}"/>
      <controls:TextComponent Text="{Binding EMP_FIRST_NAME}"/>
    </controls:MultiComponentLabel.Components>
  </controls:MultiComponentLabel>
</ContentPage>
```

Just use `MultiComponentLabel` instead of couple `Label`s

For your `ListView`

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeesList}"
          HasUnevenRows="True">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <controls:CircleImage Source="icon.png"
           HeightRequest="66"
           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           Aspect="AspectFill"
           WidthRequest="66"
           Grid.RowSpan="2" />

    <controls:MultiComponentLabel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
      <controls:MultiComponentLabel.Components>
        <controls:TextComponent Text="{Binding EMP_LAST_NAME}"/>
        <controls:TextComponent Text="{Binding EMP_FIRST_NAME}"/>
      </controls:MultiComponentLabel.Components>
    </controls:MultiComponentLabel>

  </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: how can I do that in XAML?

Comment: does it apply to a ListView?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista added code where I used it in your `ListView`

Answer (score 4):

Xamarin Forms 4.7 add support for Multibinding which can be used like this:

```
<Label>
    <Label.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="FirstName" />
            <Binding Path="LastName" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Text>
</Label>
```

In the example provided, "FirstName" and "LastName" are regular viewmodel properties defined in the class:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
```