# Concatenate StaticResources in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to concatenate two strings from string resources into a label.
I want something like this

```
<Label Content="{StaticResource Menu + " " + Name}"></Label>
```

How can I do that? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: An alternative to Ash's answer that works with any string property would be to use a `MultiBinding` with `StringFormat`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

when Content is a `string`, framework creates a TextBlock behind the scenes to display it. So

```
<Label Content="Smth"/>
```

is transformed into

```
<Label>
    <TextBlock Text="Smth"/>
</Label>
```

you can add TextBlock in xaml and explicitly assign two strings from Resources:

```
<Label>
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="{StaticResource Menu}"/>
        <Run Text="{StaticResource Name}"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Label>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :))

Comment: How would you do this in a Xamarin project? `TextBlock` is not in the Toolbox. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38199133/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-xamarin-forms) suggests using a `FormattedString` with `Span`s instead of a `TextBlock` with `Run`s but the attribute (`ClassId`) I'm trying to use it on says *Property 'ClassId' does not support values of type 'FormattedString'*